# Bootstrap 5 Navbar center logo left text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get my navigation bar to have a the toggler button on the left with the brand logo in the middle as similar to the image below

[image: Intended layout]

I am unsure how to go about doing this. My current code has button on the far left with the logo at the far right.

**CODE**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-warning">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="130" height="47" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
             <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
             <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
             -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest Bootstrap solution would be the use of the `mx-auto`-class:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-warning">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
        <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="130" height="47" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
             <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
             <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
             -->
</body>

</html>
```

Edit: To move the text/logo in the center of the viewport you need custom CSS. You need to move either the text/logo or the menu button out of flow with `position: relative/absolute` However notice that it can cause a collision issue on smaller screens depending on the width of the text/logo

```css
.navbar-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-warning">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
        <img src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="130" height="47" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
             <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
             <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
             -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is nearly there, but is there a way to make the logo perfectly centered? For example in [link](https://www.codeply.com/p/0YTcLxU86G) I made a second nav with the button removed and it centered perfectly on the second navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Put a position relative class to the container holding the navbar button and the logo. After that, add position absolute to the navbar button and just add "m-auto" to the nav-bar-brand container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link
         href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         rel="stylesheet"
         integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
         crossorigin="anonymous"
         />
      <title>Hello, world!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-warning position-relative">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute ">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand ml-auto m-auto" href="#">
            <img
               src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg"
               alt=""
               width="130"
               height="47"
               />
            </a>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
      <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
      <script
         src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
         crossorigin="anonymous"
         ></script>
      <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
      <!--
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This questions is titled and labled as `Bootstrap-5`. As such a framework solution should be used over custom CSS.

Comment: I got it. I have updated my answer to become more suitable to your question.